# How do I take a contour .shp file and create a separate layer for each elevation?

Tags: layers, tilemill, elevation, topography

The end result is to have a .dxf file in which each different elevation resides in a different layer. If at all possible I would like to be able to do the organizing in tile mill, or through some automated process. It is possible to reorder contours into layers by hand, but that's way too slow.

Other programs I have at my disposal are:
-Inkscape
-Gimp
-Draftsite

If there's another free program that would help me I'm all ears.

Comment: what GIS software are you using?  Do you have ArcMap or QGIS?  QGIS is free software that can do at least part of what you're looking for (splitting the .shp file).

Comment: Why was Tilemill tagged?

Comment: I use Tilemill to edit and overlay different .shp files. I have been told a potential workflow in QGIS by a friend that may work. I'll post it up after I confirm it works tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

A few days late, but here's a workflow that did what I needed.

Open up qGIS ( http://www.qgis.org/en/site/ )
Set up your projection under project -> project properties (I use NAD83 / Alberta 3TM ref merid 114 W EPSG:3776 but hey whatever look you want try a few) and make sure on the fly CRS transformation is checked. 
Add your .shp : Layer -> add vector layer
Right click the layer and hit zoom to layer if it doesn't appear automatically
right click the layer and hit properties
Under style set the style to Categorized, select your elevation column, and also set up your colour ramp, then hit classify. This will make a new style for each elevation
If you want to change the colours hit delete all, change the colour ramp and hit classify again.

Another option you might find useful is to try rule based styles
Make a new rule something like  ["ELEVATION"   LIKE '%00']
Where ELEVATION is the column name of the data field that contains elevation data. Right click the contour layer and hit open attribute table if you are not sure. 
This will make a rule where any data that ends in 00 will have its own style, so full numbers of feet or meters, look up sql queries for further options

From here there's two ways to export the drawing as the separate layers needed:

The easy way is to go Project -> DXF Export, this will give you a .dxf with each unique colour representing a different layer. At least that's what I got when I loaded the exported .dxf into my laser cutter. I used a fairly flat area for the test of less than 25 layers (Laser cut 6.0 maxes out at 25 layers). When I get to the mountains I want to cut the following workflow will be necessary to break it into sections for use in the laser.

For more complicated files the following may be necessary.

go project -> new print composer
Click the add new map tool
drag a box the size of the print area
On the box on the left you can change the extents (map canvas etc) and scale
Output to a PDF or SVG, and then load in illustrator or inkscape
I know in illustrator there is an option to select all items with the same stroke or colour, I use that to manually separate layers (hence why I colour separated each elevation earlier)
You could also export each altitude one at a time or rig up a script to do so.

The scrip method would be the best bet, I will post up info on that if I get it working. I highly encourage anyone with better scripting knowledge than I to do so too. :)

Happy Mapping!

-Stan